# Tracking Feed Tracking Enable checkbox

Tags: chatter, chatter-feed-tracking

i need to track changes whenever this Feed Tracking checkbox is enabled or disabled for Account Object. I need to have the visibility at user level. How do i track this? Please advice.

Comment: Check my answer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13447944/is-there-any-easy-method-available-to-know-whether-there-is-a-change-in-schema-i, maybe will be of some use?

Answer (score 2):

This information is available in your [Setup Audit Trail](http://login.salesforce.com/help/doc/en/admin_monitorsetup.htm).

> The setup audit trail history helps you track the recent setup changes
> that you and other administrators have made to your organization. This
> can be especially useful in organizations with multiple
> administrators.
>
> To view the setup audit trail history, click Your **Name | Setup |
> Security Controls | View Setup Audit Trail**. To download your
> organization’s full setup history for the past 180 days, click the
> **Download** link.
>
> The setup audit trail history shows you the 20 most recent setup
> changes made to your organization. It lists the date of the change,
> who made it, and what the change was. Additionally, if a delegate
> (such as an administrator or customer support representative) makes a
> setup change on behalf of an end-user, the Delegate User column shows
> the delegate’s username. For example, if a user grants login access to
> an administrator and the administrator makes a setup change, the
> administrator’s username is listed.

Please consult the linked documentation for a full set of what information is tracked.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! Can this be achieved from backend via SOQL or apex to check the lastmodifiedby or lastmodifieddate?

Comment: This is not data that is available through the API I believe.